# Getting the Authorization header from an http request

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know how to get the authorization header value from an http request in asp.net? I've been trying to google it but i haven't found anything on retrieving the authorization header values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Easy:

```
string value = Request.Headers["Authorization"]
```

Not something you usually handle on your own though.